# How can I get the coordinates of the touchstart event relative to the mobile device window?

Tags: jquery, ios, ios5, mobile, cordova

Here’s my JavaScript:

```
$("window").bind("touchstart", function ()
    {
        var org = e.originalEvent.touches[0]; 
        var x = orig.changedTouches[0].pageX;//relative position of html,body document
        var y = orig.changedTouches[0].pageY;//relative position of html,body document

        var x0 = x - window.scrollX;
        var y0 = y - window.scrollY;

        alert(x0);
        alert(y0);
    });
```

`x` and `y` works for coordinates relative to the HTML `body` element, so currently, 
I need to offset by `window.scrollX` or `window.scrollY`;

My problem is that during the scrolling process, a user frequently touches the device so that x0 and y0 is not correct in real time manner.

I tried to add a fullscreen transparent overlay div element using `position:fixed`, and get the coordinates relative to that:

```
 $("overlayDIV").bind("touchstart",..
```

However, the result is the same.

Is there anyway to obtain  absolute coordinates of touchstart event on mobile device window?

**my environment is iOS 5.x + phoneGap/Cordova2.0 + jQuery1.8.8.**

EDIT1

I already tried `$(window)` for the touchstart event. The problem is whatever the jQuery element is, such as `$(window)` or fullscreen transparent layer, the result is coordinates relative to `html,body`.

EDIT2

According to
http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

```
event.pageX
The mouse position relative to the left edge of the document.
event.pageY
The mouse position relative to the top edge of the document.
```

as long as we use pageX property, the return will be always **relative position of the document**. It may sound fine but the problem is it's actually **relative position of html, body document**.

Comment: Try to use `$(window)` instead of `$("html,body")`.

Comment: @yckart thanks, but I already tried $(window) for the touchstart event. 

The problem is whatever the jQuery element is, 

such as $(window) or fullscreen transparent layer,

the result is html,body relative coordination.

Comment: Great question. Just to check, are your results incorrect because of the use of `scrollX` instead of `scrollY` in this line: `var y0 = y - window.scrollX;`? Or is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: Sorry, it was my typo, and I modified. My mobile application behaves fine as expected in most of times, but often, during the scrolling process, due to some delay, the expected touched coordination are not calculated correctly.